# Как реализовать checker для задач по С++?

Tags: c++, c

Нужно написать программу (тестировщик) для проверки других программ на корректность вывода.

Например есть задача. Считать с клавиатуры два числа, поделить их и вывести в консоль результат.

*Пример 1 

Входные данные: 12 2

Выходные данные: 6

Пример 2

Входные данные: 5 0

Выходные данные: error*

**Вопрос как в программу(тестировщик) передать выходные данные другой программы ?**

Comment: Через конвейер, например. В курсе, что в командной строке `a | b` означает, что то, что подается на выход программы `a`, поступает на вход `b`? `a > b` - вывод программы `a` перенаправлен в *файл* `b`. `a < b` - на вход `a` подается информация из *файла* `b`. [Ностальгически] дожились... народ ничего не знает о командной строке...

Comment: Ну или нестандартной в смысле С/С++, но обычно реализованной `popen`.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду разбираться.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы используете QT Creator то можно поступить так (смотрите пример кода):

В файл проекта (*.pro) добавить строку:

```
QT       += core
```

В файле *.cpp метод для чтения ответа из консоли:

```
……………………..
#include <QProcess>
……………………..
void MainWindow::on_pushButtonReadSerialHDD_pressed()
{
    QProcess prc;
    prc.start("wmic", QStringList() << "diskdrive" << "get" << "model,name,serialnumber"); // это вызов системной команды wmic, но Вы можете подставить свою тестируемую программу и сформировать ей командную строку
    if (!prc.waitForStarted())
    {
        ui->textEdit->append("Process not started");
        return;
    }
    if (!prc.waitForFinished())
    {
        ui->textEdit->append("Process not finished");
        return;
    };
    QByteArray result = prc.readAll(); // Прочесть ответ тестируемой программы в консоль
    prc.close();

    // Здесь можете разместить код для анализа полученного результата

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно результат возвращать в main'e из основной программы, а то что возвратили — посылать как аргументы в программу, что проверяет. Или как второй вариант — записать результат в файл в первой программе, а во второй — считать информацию с файла и анализировать.